# Python reading unopened files from a folder

Tags: python, file, os.walk

Is there a way to read all the unopened files in a folder only by passing the one specific file name that is present in that folder?I know to read all the files in a directory passing the directory name using os.walk.But in this specific problem I can just pass only one file name.Need your help for this problem.Thank you.

Comment: You can't read a file that isn't open, that's not how a file works. Why are you only able to pass one filename?

Comment: The requirement is so.I can pass only the file name.then i have read all the files in that folder.

Comment: please provide a [well-formed example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: how do you define "unopened file"? You have to open it to read it.

Comment: Your requirement makes no sense. Is the requirement that you can only provide on path at the command line? in which case `os.listdir(path)` is your friend. Otherwise, if you can only ever pass one filename, you can only ever read from one file. That's just how things work.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have a path of a single file, while you want to read all files in the folder it's located in.

You can achieve this easily:

```
dir_name, file_name = os.path.split(filepath)
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_name):
    for file in files:
        with open(file) as f:
            file_content = f.read()
```